# Show your app on share via android?

Tags: android

Hi I would like to ask if somebody knew on how to implement when a user press the share via on there mobile device i would like to see the installed app that i created? example a when a user want to share a photo ?

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bloxofcode.fab">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What's happening in your case? I think the registration in manifest is okay.

Comment: @iamcoder do you want display your app name there at share intent?

Comment: Hi sir thanks for the reply. I think i manage to view it by adding series of multiple intents based on this document.
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

But now my problem is how can i get the photo path ?
    void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
        Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (imageUri != null) {
            // Update UI to reflect image being shared
            Log.d("Path",imageUri.Path) ??????
        }
    }